# How concerned should we be about Mice coming into the baby's room?

Tags: infant, newborn, hygiene

Our first child is due any day now, and we've got a mouse infestation. We noticed it for the first time at my girlfriend's baby shower (lots of cakes and crumbs out), and since then we've started seeing it more frequently. I say "it", but we suspect more than one of them, based on other people's comments.

Obviously we're trying to [de-mouse the house](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13758/how-to-deal-with-mice-coming-into-the-babys-room), but **how concerned should we be about mice in a house with a child?**

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with parenting. You may want to consult with an exterminator.

Comment: This question seems to be less about parenting and more about [home improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) -- at least [mouse infestations are discussed frequently](http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=mice) there.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll migrate.

Comment: I've actually edited the question to be more parenting-related, as I think this is a common concern for young parents.

Comment: We're currently evaluating our site, and this question is one we are seeking feedback on. Everyone, please visit [this meta question](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/343/parenting-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical) and chime in with your thoughts and votes!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some studies ([news article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/health/1065961.stm), [another article](http://www.sixwise.com/newsletters/05/03/01/that-little-mouse-in-your-house-is-even-more-dangerous-than-we-thought.htm), [actual study](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0091674907001704)) have shown that mice fecal matter could contribute to asthma, or otherwise cause allergies in young children.

> In a study of eight cities, a team from Johns Hopkins University in
>   Baltimore, US, checked the contents of dust samples from the homes of
>   children with asthma.
>
> The team found that 95% of those samples contained mouse allergens,
>   many involving feces or urine.

Other concerns include: mouse droppings can pose to be a choking hazard; mice can eat up your furniture, wiring, and insulation; they may clog plumbing etc. in your house, creating fire hazards; and [much more](http://lsmalley1.xomba.com/dangers_of_rodent_infestation).

> Murine Typhus Fever or simply Typhus is spread by the bites of fleas
>   that have fed off of rodents. This infectious disease shows itself
>   with a rash and other symptoms include headache, backache, a high
>   fever that may last up to two weeks, nausea, vomiting, and abdominal
>   pain. Treatment for typhus fever includes antibiotics and over 98% of
>   people afflicted will recover. 10% to 60% of people who do not go on
>   antibiotic treatment will not survive

Living with a mice infestation is dangerous for human beings in general; it is only going to be more dangerous for a helpless child to be there.

Answer (score 2):

No more than in a house without a child. Which is to say, *the mice have to go*. Mice leak urine as they walk -- "like drunken hoboes," as MimiSmartyPants so memorably put it last year. They're nasty little brutes.

First, seal up your foundation. (I did it last year and it took half a bag of cement and four cans of spray foam. Thank you, lazy house-builder!) Then buy some spring traps, smear on peanut butter, and place them near the basement walls. Get ready to collect the little bodies.

Comment: Rented accomodation from the 1900's. Suspect that sealing the foundation may be a tad harder for us.

Good advice on the traps, thanks.

Comment: Oh, that makes it harder. Yeah, you may be forced to launch a Reign Of Terror in mouseland. My condolences: sometimes it gets downright nasty. :7(

Comment: Third, get a cat or three.